# Archive TODO by completion date, not archive date

Tags: org-mode

Just spinning up on emacs and `org-mode`.  Apologies if this is a trivial question, but haven't come across an answer yet after a fair amount of searching.  I have my `#+SEQ_TODO` set up to record completion dates, and my archive file set as `"file"_archive.org::datetree/`. When I archive a task in the `DONE` state, I would like to have it archived to the datetree under a **completion** date heading, not under the date that I get around to archiving it.  Any help would be appreciated.